# There are $n$ sticks of length $\{1,2,3,\cdots,n\} $. how many incongruent triangles can be made using those sticks

Tags: combinatorics

**My Approach:** Let the number of incongruent triangles possible with the sticks of length $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ is $S_n $

So now number of incongruent triangles possible with the sticks of length $\{1,2,\cdots,n,n+1\}=$ Number of incongruent triangles with the sticks of length $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}+$ Number of incongruent triangles with largest side $n+1 $ $\implies S_{n+1}=S_n+$ Number of incongruent triangles with largest side $n+1 $

Now we will find the number of possible triangles with largest side $n+1$

Now the smallest side has to be greater than 1. The sum of two sides other than largest side can be minimum $n+2$ and maximum $2n-1$

\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Smallest Side length}& \text{Number of choices to choose third side}\\ \hline
2 & 1\ [\text{Only } n]\\
3 & 2\ [\text{Only } n,n-1]\\
4 & 3\  [\text{Only } n,n-1,n-2]\\
\vdots & \vdots \quad \quad\quad\vdots \\
\Big\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2}\Big\rfloor & \Big\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2}\Big\rfloor-1\\ \hline
\text{Total} & \dfrac{\Big\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2}\Big\rfloor\bigg(\Big\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2}\Big\rfloor-1\bigg)}{2}
\end{array}

**Case 1 ($n=2k$):**  Then $\Big\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2}\Big\rfloor=k$ Then after k we can choose any two lengths from the sticks $\{k+1,k+2,\cdots,n\}$. So then number of choices when smallest side is $k+1$ is $\dfrac{k (k-1)}{2}$

Hence $S_{n+1}=S_n+\dfrac{k (k-1)}{2}+\dfrac{k (k-1)}{2}=S_n+k (k-1)= S_n+\dfrac{n (n-2)}{4}$

**Case 2 ($n=2k+1$):** Then $\Big\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2}\Big\rfloor=k$.  Here after k we can choose any two lengths from the sticks $\{k+1,k+2,\cdots,n\}$. So now the number of choices when smallest side is $k+1$ is $\dfrac{k (k+1)}{2}$

Hence $S_{n+1}=S_n+\dfrac{k (k-1)}{2}+\dfrac{k (k+1)}{2}=S_n+k^2 = S_n+\dfrac{(n-1)^2}{4}$

Now i got these two recurrence relation but how to solve that to a general formula?

**Edit:** I got the rest.

We got that $$\text{Number of incongruent triangles with largest side }n+1=\begin{cases} \dfrac{n (n-2)}{4}, & \text{when }n=\text{even}\\ \dfrac{(n-1)^2}{4}, & \text{when }n=\text{odd}\end{cases}$$we can write it in this way that $$\text{Number of incongruent triangles with largest side }n+1=\bigg\lceil \dfrac{n (n-2)}{4}\bigg\rceil$$

Now, \begin{array}{ccccc}
S_{n+1}& - & S_n & = & \bigg\lceil \dfrac{n (n-2)}{4}\bigg\rceil \\
S_{n}    & - & S_{n-1} & = & \bigg\lceil \dfrac{(n-1)(n-3)}{4}\bigg\rceil \\
S_{n-1} & - & S_{n-2} & = & \bigg\lceil \dfrac{(n-2)(n-4)}{4}\bigg\rceil \\
\vdots &    & \vdots &      & \vdots\\ 
S_4      & - & S_3 & =& \bigg\lceil \dfrac{3 (3-2)}{4}\bigg\rceil =1\\ \hline
S_{n+1}&- & S_3 & = & \sum\limits_{i=3}^n \bigg\lceil \dfrac{i (i-2)}{4}\bigg\rceil\\
S_{n+1}&  &         & = &\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \bigg\lceil \dfrac{i (i-2)}{4}\bigg\rceil 
\end{array}

Comment: It might be an idea to calculate a few terms of this sequence and enter it into [OEIS](http://oeis.org/). That often solves problems like this.

Comment: It might also be an idea to search this website for previous occurrences of this question. I'm quite confident it has been asked and answered here before.

Comment: [Number of Triangles Using Rods of Lengths 1, 2, …, n](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1051808/318073)

Comment: Have you followed up on any of these comments, Soham?

Comment: It's not polite to ask a question, Soham, and then ignore people who try to help you to answer it.

Comment: How can i answer when my wifi was not working for some days...however you said that " it might also be an idea to search this website for previous occurrences of this question. I'm quite confident it has been asked and answered here before. " ---my question is if this approach is correct or not...i am not asking what is the answer of the problem

Comment: Sorry about your wifi problems, Soham. But have you looked for previous occurrences of this question? You might find that not only has the question been asked and answered before, but that exactly your approach has been taken, and the reception it got may tell you what you want to know. So: have you followed up on any of the comments? By the way, if you want to be sure that I see a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: Sorry but i cant understand the summation part he did @Gerry

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are referring to, Soham. Does this have to do with the post @Vepir linked? Anyway, asking for clarification of some other solution is not the same as asking for confirmation of your approach, so it seems to me you're changing the question. So, what exactly do you want?

Comment: I am asking is my approach is right or wrong ? If wrong then point out the mistakes...thats all

Comment: Again you left out the @Gerry, Soham. But you haven't answered my question as to whether you have followed up on the comments.

Comment: Yeah i followed the comments @Gerry