# Number of acute triangles using rods of lengths $1, 2, \ldots, n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

> **Problem.** Suppose one has exactly $n \geq 3$ rods, which have lengths $1,\ldots,n$.
>
> How many non-degenerate acute triangles can be formed using these rods?

(*Clarification:* You must use precisely $3$ rods in each triangle. Concatenation of rods along a side is not allowed, and reusing of any rod is not allowed like $\{1,1,1\}$.)

Almost same to [Number of Triangles Using Rods of Lengths 1, 2, ..., n](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1051808/1078889), but needs acute triangles.

I run a quick bench on Python,

```
from itertools import combinations
lst = []
for n in range(3,33):
    cnt=0
    for a,b,c in combinations(range(1,n+1),3):
        if a+b>c and a**2+b**2>c**2:
            cnt+=1
    lst.append(cnt)
print(lst)
```

and I got

> [0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 22, 32, 43, 56, 71, 90, 112, 137, 165, 196, 232, 271, 315, 364, 416, 473, 535, 603, 677, 756, 842, 933]

but there was no correct one in OEIS.
So what's the exact formula of this?

Comment: Looks like this sequence is not on OEIS.

Comment: By the way: condition $a+b>c$ in your code is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update History.**

*Edit #1.* The original answer did not take the condition $c \leq n$ into consideration. A new answer fixed this.

*Edit #2.* A minor error found in the formula for $A_n$. The net effect was that the previous answer estimated $A_{n-1}$ instead of $A_n$. This is now corrected.

---

Note that the $n$th term $A_n$ is given by

\begin{align*}
A_n
&= \sum_{1 \leq a < b < c \leq n} \mathbf{1}_{\{ c^2 < a^2 + b^2\}} \\
&= \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} \sum_{c \in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbf{1}_{\{b+1 \leq c < \lceil \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \rceil \text{ and } b \leq n\}} \\
&= \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} \left( \left\lceil {\textstyle\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \right\rceil \wedge (n+1)  - b - 1 \right),
\end{align*}

where $x \wedge y = \min\{x, y\}$. The presence of the term $\lceil\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \rceil$ term suggests that lower-order terms in the asymptotic expansion of $A_n$ will be susceptible to the number-theoretic properties of the lattice points in circles, which is known to be a very hard problem. (See [Gauss's circle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem).) So, I guess that there is no simple and exact formula for $A_n$.

#### 1. Leading Term

First, we study the leading term in the asymptotic expansion of $A_n$. As $n \to \infty$,

\begin{align*}
\frac{A_n}{n^3}
&= \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} \left( \biggl\lceil \sqrt{\Bigl(\frac{a}{n}\Bigr)^2 + \Bigl(\frac{b}{n}\Bigr)^2} \biggr\rceil \wedge \frac{n+1}{n} - \frac{b+1}{n} \right) \frac{1}{n^2} \\
&\to \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} \bigl( {\textstyle \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \wedge 1 - y \bigr) \, \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{6} - \frac{\pi}{24}.
\end{align*}

This shows that

$$ \bbox[color:navy;padding:5px;border:1px navy dotted;]{ A_n = \left( \frac{1}{6} - \frac{\pi}{24} \right) n^3 + o(n^3). } $$

#### 2. Second Term

We now turn to extracting the second-order term. To analyze the behavior of $A_n$, we decompose it as

\begin{align*}
A_n
&= \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} \left\lceil {\textstyle\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \right\rceil \wedge (n + 1)
- \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} (b+1)
\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{1 \leq a, b \leq n} \left\lceil {\textstyle\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \right\rceil \wedge (n + 1)
- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{1 \leq a \leq n}\left\lceil \sqrt{2} a \right\rceil \wedge (n+1)
- \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} (b+1)
\\
&= \frac{1}{8} \sum_{|a|, |b| \leq n} \left\lceil {\textstyle\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \right\rceil \wedge (n + 1)
- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{1 \leq a \leq n} a \\
&\qquad - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{1 \leq a \leq n} \left\lceil \sqrt{2} a \right\rceil \wedge (n + 1)
- \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} (b+1). \tag{1}
\end{align*}

We first estimate easier parts. It is straightforward to check that

\begin{align*}
- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{1 \leq a \leq n} a
- \sum_{1 \leq a \leq b \leq n} (b+1)
&= -\frac{n^3}{3} + -\frac{3n^2}{4} + \frac{7n}{12}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Also,

\begin{align*}
- \frac{1}{2} \sum_{1 \leq a \leq n} \left\lceil \sqrt{2} a \right\rceil \wedge (n+1)
&= -\frac{n^2}{2} \left( \int_{0}^{1}  ( \sqrt{2} x ) \wedge 1 \, \mathrm{d}x \right) + o(n^2) \\
&= \left( \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{2} \right) n^2 + o(n^2). \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Now we turn to estimating the hardest part. Write $N(r) = \# \{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : \|z\| \leq r\}$ for the number of lattice points within a distance of $n$ from the origin. Then [it is known that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem)

$$ N(r) = \pi r^2 + o(r). \tag{4} $$

Using this, we decompose the first sum in $\text{(1)}$ as

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{|a|, |b| \leq n} \left\lceil {\textstyle\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \right\rceil \wedge (n+1) \\
&= \sum_{\substack{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\ \|z\| \leq n}} \|z\|
+ \sum_{\substack{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\ \|z\| \leq n}} (\left\lceil \|z\| \right\rceil - \|z\|)
+ \sum_{|a|, |b| \leq n} (n + 1) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{ a^2 + b^2 > n^2 \}}. \tag{5}
\end{align*}

Then the first sum in the right-hand side of $\text{(5)}$ is

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\ \|z\| \leq n}} \|z\|
&= \sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \left( \int_{0}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{\{r < \|z\| \}} \, \mathrm{d}r \right) \mathbf{1}_{\{\|z\| \leq n\}}
= \int_{0}^{n} \left( \sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \mathbf{1}_{\{r < \|z\| \leq n \}} \right) \, \mathrm{d}r \\
&= \int_{0}^{n} \left( N(n) - N(r) \right) \, \mathrm{d}r
\stackrel{\text{(4)}}= \frac{2\pi}{3} n^3 + o(n^2).
\end{align*}

Arguing similarly, we can show that $\{ \left\lceil \|z\| \right\rceil - \|z\| : z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \text{ and } \|z\| \leq n\}$ is equidistributed on $[0, 1]$, hence the second sum in $\text{(5)}$ is

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\ \|z\| \leq n}} (\left\lceil \|z\| \right\rceil - \|z\|)
&= \frac{\pi}{2} n^2 + o(n^2).
\end{align*}

Finally, the last sum in $\text{(5)}$ reduces to

\begin{align*}
\sum_{|a|, |b| \leq n} (n+1) \cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{ a^2 + b^2 > n^2 \}}
&= (n+1) \left[ (2n+1)^2 - N(n) \right] \\
&= (4-\pi) n^3 + (8 -\pi) n^2 + o(n^2)
\end{align*}

Plugging these three estimates to $\text{(5)}$, we get

$$
\sum_{|a|, |b| \leq n} \left\lceil {\textstyle\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \right\rceil \wedge (n+1)
= \left(4 - \frac{\pi}{3} \right) n^3 - \left( 8 - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) n^2 + o(n^2). \tag{6}
$$

Then combining $\text{(2)}$, $\text{(3)}$, and $\text{(6)}$, it follows that

\begin{align*}
\bbox[color:navy;padding:5px;border:1px navy dotted;]{ A_n
= \left(\frac{1}{6} - \frac{\pi}{24} \right) n^3 + \left( - \frac{\pi}{16} + \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{4}\right) n^2 + o(n^2). }
\end{align*}

#### 3. Numerical Experiments

I tested the following ansatz for the asymptotic formula of $A_n$:

$$ A_n = c_3 n^3 + c_2 n^2 + c_{3/2} n^{3/2} + c_1 n + c_{1/2} \sqrt{n} + c_0 + E_n, \tag{7} $$

where the true values of $c_3$ and $c_2$ are

\begin{align*}
c_3 &= \frac{1}{6} - \frac{\pi}{24}
&& \approx 0.035766972767091948397\ldots, \\
c_2 &= - \frac{\pi}{16} + \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{2}} - \frac{1}{4}
&& \approx -0.26957284555272519630\ldots
\end{align*}

The graph below shows estimated valued of $c_3, c_2, c_{3/2}, c_1, c_{1/2}, c_0$ using the data $(A_1, \ldots, A_n)$ for $n$ between $100$ and $800$, using least squares fitting. In the first row, the dashed lines represent the exact value of $c_3$ and $c_2$.

[image: LSF]

This suggests that the third term in the asymptotic expansion of $A_n$ is indeed of the form $c_{3/2} x^{3/2}$ for some constant $c_{3/2}$. On the other hand, further lower-order terms seem suffering from a kind of pseudo-randomness.

---

**Addendum: Proof of Equidistribution Theorem.**

> **Lemma.** For any Riemann integrable $f$, we have
>
> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\pi n^2} \sum_{\substack{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\ \|z\| \leq n}} f(\left\lceil \|z\| \right\rceil - \|z\|)
> = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

*Proof.* We will follow the standard approach. If the claim can be proved for $f \in C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$, then the general claim for Riemann integrable $f$ will follow by approximating $f$ from above and below by continuous functions. Then by noting that the set of trigonometric polynomials are dense in $C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ equipped with the uniform norm, the claim boils down to proving the [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl%27s_criterion)

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\pi n^2} \sum_{\substack{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\ \|z\| \leq n}} e^{2\pi i \ell \|z\|}
= \mathbf{1}_{\{ \ell = 0\}} \qquad \forall \ell \in \mathbb{Z}. $$

Indeed, the sum in the limit is recast as

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\substack{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\ \|z\| \leq n}} e^{2\pi i \ell \|z\|}
&= \sum_{\substack{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\ \|z\| \leq n}} \left( 1 + \int_{0}^{\|z\|} 2\pi i \ell e^{2\pi i \ell r} \, \mathrm{d}r \right) \\
&= N(n) + \int_{0}^{n} \Biggl( \sum_{\substack{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \\ \|z\| < n}} \mathbf{1}_{\{ r < \|z\| \leq n\}} \Biggr) 2\pi i \ell e^{2\pi i \ell r} \, \mathrm{d}r \\
&= N(n) + \int_{0}^{n} (\pi (n^2 - r^2) + o(n) ) 2\pi i \ell e^{2\pi i \ell r} \, \mathrm{d}r \\
&= \begin{cases}
\pi n^2 + o(n^2), & \ell = 0, \\
o(n^2), & \ell \neq 0,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

where we utilized $\text{(4)}$ in the penultimate step. Therefore the desired claim follows. $\square$

Comment: @Empy2, Thank you for pointing out the error. I now fixed my answer, as well as redo the simulations.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between consecutive terms is the number of triangles with longest side $n$.  This number is the number of lattice points in the triangle $0\lt x\lt y\lt n$, outside the circle $x^2+y^2=n^2$.  That will be about $(\frac12-\frac{\pi}8)n^2$, so the leading order for the OP's sequence would be $$\left(\frac12-\frac\pi 8\right)\frac{n^3}3+o(n^3)$$

Comment: Also see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem